# UIDatePicker and NSDateFormatter timezone issue

Tags: ios, timezone, nsdateformatter, uidatepicker

I see some strange behavior when using NSDateFormatter and UIDatePicker.
Here is the code:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *hourFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];

NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [hourFormatter.calendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:now];

UIDatePicker* picker = [UIDatePicker new];
NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@ %@", dateComponents, hourFormatter.calendar, picker.calendar, [NSCalendar currentCalendar]);


picker.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];

NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@ %@", dateComponents, hourFormatter.calendar, picker.calendar, [NSCalendar currentCalendar]);

dateComponents = [hourFormatter.calendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@ %@", dateComponents, hourFormatter.calendar, picker.calendar, [NSCalendar currentCalendar]);

[UIDatePicker new];
dateComponents = [hourFormatter.calendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:now];

NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@ %@", dateComponents, hourFormatter.calendar, picker.calendar, [NSCalendar currentCalendar]);
```

The output is next:

```
<NSDateComponents: 0x8b8e3e0>
Hour: 10 <__NSCFCalendar: 0x8b8ddc0> <_NSCopyOnWriteCalendarWrapper: 0x8b90580> <_NSCopyOnWriteCalendarWrapper: 0x8b907b0>
<NSDateComponents: 0x8b8e3e0>
Hour: 10 <__NSCFCalendar: 0x8b8ddc0> <_NSCopyOnWriteCalendarWrapper: 0x8dc99f0> <_NSCopyOnWriteCalendarWrapper: 0x8dc9af0>
<NSDateComponents: 0x8a89fb0>
Hour: 18 <__NSCFCalendar: 0x8b8ddc0> <_NSCopyOnWriteCalendarWrapper: 0x8a8af60> <_NSCopyOnWriteCalendarWrapper: 0x8a8ac10>
<NSDateComponents: 0x8dc9a40>
Hour: 10 <__NSCFCalendar: 0x8b8ddc0> <_NSCopyOnWriteCalendarWrapper: 0x8dca1c0> <_NSCopyOnWriteCalendarWrapper: 0x8dca1d0>
```

So the question is - why changing timeZone in UIDatePicker causes different hour component to be created?

UPDATE:
added calendar logging

Comment: I guess you are dealing with same instance of NSCalendar. Log hourFormatter.calendar, picker.calendar, [NSCalendar currentCalendar].

Comment: Updated question according to your suggestion. It gives me hint, and the next line causes that formatter will no longer to be dependent on picker change: hourFormatter.calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

Comment: Another way to fix the issue - assign brand new calendar to picker : picker.calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] calendarIdentifier]];